# chart not showing when executed in c#

Tags: c#, charts, highcharts, transactions

I have a point of sales system for a burger store and I want to create a chart which shows the sales for that day. The code was correct, however when I tested it. the chart wasn't showing at all after the transaction. [image: transaction proper]

[image: sales chart after transaction]

the codes for these two are as follows:

(after the transaction and saving the transaction)

```
void paymentSuccess(object sender, PaymentMadeEventArgs e)
        {

            TblTransaction transaction = new TblTransaction();
            transaction.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;


            if (e.PaymentSuccess == true)
            {
                //save the current transaction 


                foreach (TblProduct product in products)
                {
                    transaction.TblTransactionItems.Add(new TblTransactionItem() { ProductID = product.ProductID });

                }

                rde.AddToTblTransactions(transaction);
                rde.SaveChanges();
            }
```

(my code on the chart):

```
private void generateGraph()
        {



            using (RanchoPOSDatabaseEntities rde = new RanchoPOSDatabaseEntities()) //inherits the database class of the main form into a private class
            {
                var query = from product in rde.TblTransactionItems    //var ay isang datatype na iniindicate na hindi defined kung anong data ang ipapasok sa system
                            group product by product.TblProduct.Description into g  //groups products by their description at ilalagay sa variable na 'g'
                            select new { ProductID = g.Key, TotalUnitSold = g.Count() };  //display data base on primary key and the number of items sold


                chart1.DataSource = query; //binds the query to the chart1 
                chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "ProductID";
                chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "TotalUnitSold";

                chart1.Series["Series1"].Name = "Products";

                chart1.DataBind();

                chart1.Show();
            }
```

I am using `c#` 2010 with `SQL Server 2008` as medium, can some look for any corrections in this>

Comment: Use the debugger to check if query does indeed contain data!

Comment: Are you sure is this Highcharts library, you use for generating charts?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using the debugger right now and this happens [error during debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7drX.png)

normally, it runs smoothly.
what is the meaning of the error?